# Title in Markdown toc.yml

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, title, tableofcontents

I'm looking for a way to add titles in the markdown toc.yml files. Could anyone help?

In normal links I would use this way:

HTML

```
<a href="#mylink" title="My title"> I am a link </a>
```

Markdown Normal Link

```
[I am a link] (# mylink "my title")
```

Makdown Link Toc.yml

```
- name: I am a link
   href: #mylink
   title: ???
```

How to add a title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/intro_toc.html), there is **no `title` attribute** in Table-Of-Content files. You should include the textual information in the name of the given link.

An alternative approach would be using Markdown for your TOC, which, as you mentioned, supports titling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I've tried using the basic markdown link "[I am a link] (# mylink "my title")" and the TOC.YML does not allow the attribute.